# Anki: mathjax equations not rendering

Tags: automation, mathjax, anki

I am using anki with a deck I found online [here](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/29414135). The deck must have been made with an old version of anki, or I am missing plugins as most of the equations do not render; most appear in the raw, unformatted form surrounded with '$' symbols.

I can use the inline mathjax editor to manually fix this by deleting the $ symbols from either side and inputting the equation. There are hundreds of cards and I don't particularly want to fix each one manually. Can someone help with how to automate this/fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I just manually changed each card to new formatting standards. There was probably an easier way I didn't know.